# Why is the custom font applying to other elements of the list?

Tags: android, layout, fonts, android-adapter

I have a list in which I show some contacts. To make things easier, the last element of the list is an add button to add another contact. The add button is an + icon using a special font. The problem that I have and that it drives me crazy, is that when I scroll the list down and come back up, sometimes (not always) the top contacts change their fonts to this special font and if I scroll back down it happens the same to the other ones. Do you know what the problem is?

This is my adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Contact> _data;
private Typeface font;
Context _c;

CustomAdapter (ArrayList<Contact> data, Context c, Typeface font){
    _data = data;
    _c = c;
    this.font=font;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return _data.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     View v = convertView;
     if (v == null)
     {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)_c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null);
     }

       ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_single);
       TextView name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name_single);


       Contact msg = _data.get(position);

       image.setImageBitmap(msg.getBlurredPhoto());
       name.setText(msg.getName());
       //to make sure that the font only applies to the add button, I also gave it 
       //the phone number "1"
       if((position==_data.size()-1)&&(msg.getNumber().equals("1"))){
          name.setTypeface(font);
          name.setText(R.string.icon_add);
          name.setTextColor(0xFF2c3e50);

       }


    return v;
}
}
```

And this is the layout for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/photo_single"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
         />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/name_single"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recycling rows, but you are never resetting the font. If you call `setTypeface()` to set the special font on special rows, you also need to call `setTypeface()` to return to the regular font on regular rows.

Or, implement `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`, so your special-font row is recycled separately from other types of rows.

Comment: Thanks! The first option seams to work. How would you implement `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` to change the font for only the last element?

Comment: @Gunoi: In your case, `getViewTypeCount()` will return `2`. `getItemViewType()` would return `0` for everything but the magic row, which would return `1`.